# Unexpected equal sign in php when creating PDO object

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

config.php

```
<?php
    try{
        connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=9lessons;host=localhsot", "root", "");
    }catch(PDOException $error){
        echo $error->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

main.php

```
<?php
    include ('config.php');
    foreach ($connection->query('SELECT * FROM message LIMIT 9') as $row)
    {
        $msg = $row['msg'];
        $mes_id=$row['mes_id'];
        $up=$row['up'];
        $down=$row['down'];
 ?>
<div class="main">
<div class="box1">
<div class="up">
<a href=""class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id?>" name="up">
<?php echo $up; ?></a></div>

<div class="down">
<a href="" class="vote" id="<?php echo $mes_id; ?>" name="down">
<?php echo $down; ?></a></div>
</div>
<div class="box2"><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

When I run the piece of code above, I got error message as follows:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=' in C:\xampp\htdocs\config.php on line 3
```

Comment: `localhsot` typo - do `localhost` - Plus, you probably shouldn't use leading numbers in DB names. Edit: Plus `connection` to `$connection`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Variables start with a `$`:

```
$connection = new PDO("mysql:dbname=9lessons;host=localhsot", "root", "");
```

Anytime you have a `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected` - find the unexpected thing and slowly backtrack looking for a syntax error.

Comment: You missed `localhsot`

Comment: That doesn't cause the error, and maybe his hostname is `localhsot`? :-)

Comment: ...we'll wait for the OP's response, how 'bout that? ;)